# Android button setColorFilter behaviour

Tags: android, button

(I changed the question a bit, because the problem is a bit clearer now)

I have 4 buttons on my application, and when a user clickes certain button
I change that button color.

when button 3 is clicked I want to change his color to green, otherwise I want remove his green filter (when button1/2/4 are clicked).
If I click on button 3 It does get the green filter. If then I click button 4 it removes the green filter, but if I click button 1 or 2, nothing happens.
When I switched the position of the buttons in the XML, and put button3 first, It doesnt happen, ideas?

The relevant part of the layout xml is:

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/ans1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<Button
android:id="@+id/ans2"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<Button
android:id="@+id/ans3"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<Button
android:id="@+id/ans4"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

The code is:

```
if (answer.equals("3")) 
    {
        question.setText("In if");
        d.setColorFilter(filter); 
    }
    else
    {
        question.setText("else");
        d.setColorFilter(null);
    }
```

Comment: Please post the *complete* code necessary to replicate the problem.

Comment: It seems that you need a `RadioButton`

Comment: I know radiobutton seems like areasonable solution, but I do really need buttons. I have posted an updated question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5715944/android-button-setcolorfilter-behaviour

Answer (score 5):

I seem to remember having issues when creating too many ColorFilters before. It doesn't sound for certain like that's what's at fault here, since it's happening right away. Still, what you might try is having the filter as a class variable, and then using it within the if/else block. Also, as Trev mentioned, since you're just wanting to remove the green filter, you can just pass null to setColorFilter and avoid making the transparent filter, so you'd end up with something like this:

```
//in main class
PorterDuffColorFilter greenFilter = 
    new PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.GREEN, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);

//in CheckAnswer()
Drawable d = findViewById(R.id.ans2).getBackground();

if(answer.equals("1") d.setColorFilter(greenFilter)
else d.setColorFilter(null);
```

Comment: I tried It, but still doesnt work. I wrote the question from scratch here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5715944/android-button-setcolorfilter-behaviour

Comment: What if the initial button has already a filter? Or can we assume that the default system themed button does not have a filter? Or do we need to chain filters?

Comment: BTW: There is also a clearColorFilter() method. Which is a convenience method for setColorFilter(null).

Answer (score 4):

The default behavior when calling `setColorFilter(ColorFilter)` on a `Drawable` does not automatically invalidate the `Drawable`, meaning it will not redraw itself solely as a result of the method call.

Try calling `d.invalidateSelf()` after setting the `ColorFilter`.

Answer (score 2):

Yesterday I posted a suggestion to a very similar problem that you asked here:

[Android button setColorFilter behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5702521/android-button-setcolorfilter-behaviour/5702883#5702883)

It appears that you have edited the code you originally posted there in order to incorporate the suggestions you were given (without acknowledging the answers) and then posted exactly the same code in this question.

Comment: Yes, I will comment there. I asked It again because It is clearer now, and most pepole wont read the question again. I dont really like it, but what else could I have done?

Answer (score 1):

The Drawable documentation regarding setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) states that 'null' may be passed to remove any existing filters. So, perhaps it could be that once the TRANSPARENT filter has been applied, then your subsequent GREEN filter can't be seen? I don't know enough about .setColorFilter and PorterDuff to know for sure, but it's worth a shot. Perhaps try:

```
d.setColorFilter(null); 
d.setColorFilter(filter);
```

Also you could instead use this method:

```
setColorFilter(int color, PorterDuff.Mode mode)
```

Comment: I tried the null, and also tried clearColorFilter(), But with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to mutate each drawable before setColorFilter.

```
Drawable d = findViewById(R.id.ans2).getBackground();

d = d.mutate();
d.setColorFilter
```