# Android button setColorFilter behaviour

Tags: android, button, colorfilter

I have 4 buttons on my application, and when a user clickes certain button I change that button color.

when button 3 is clicked I want to change his color to green, otherwise I want remove his green filter (when button1/2/4 are clicked). If I click on button 3 It does get the green filter. If then I click button 4 it removes the green filter, but if I click button 1 or 2, nothing happens. When I switched the position of the buttons in the XML, and put button3 first, It doesnt happen, ideas?

10x :)

The relevant part of the layout xml is:

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/ans1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<Button
android:id="@+id/ans2"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<Button
android:id="@+id/ans3"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<Button
android:id="@+id/ans4"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

The Relevant code is:

```
PorterDuffColorFilter filter = new PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.GREEN,Mode.SRC_ATOP);
    if (answer.equals("3")) 
    {
        question.setText("In if");
        d.setColorFilter(filter); 
    }
    else
    {
        question.setText("else");
        d.setColorFilter(null);
    }
```